# HTMLAgilityPack Skip HTML table caption

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have an html table like below:

```
<table>
    <caption>Table 2</caption>
    <tr><td>hd1</td><td>hd2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>val01</td><td>val02</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <table>
                <caption>Subtable 2</caption>
                <tr><td>subval01</td><td>subval02</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT**
Here is my code:

```
            foreach (HtmlNode rows in htmltable.SelectNodes("tr"))
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                int iRow = 0;
                if (!rows.InnerHtml.Contains("<caption>"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in rows.SelectNodes("td"))
                    {
                        iRow++;
                        dr[iRow] = cell.InnerText;
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
```

My code recognizing `<caption>` as row and selecting it as well.
I don't get how to skip caption while parsing. So I can parse ONLY the rows.`Skip(1)` method is not working for me.

Comment: what elements *do* you want to parse? It's very unclear as stated

Comment: @BrokenGlass I'm converting this table into C# Datatable and I don't want the captions. Only the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you want to skip `<tr>` having descendant node `<caption>` (the last `<tr>` within outer `<table>` tag). In this case we can use XPath to select only `<tr>` that doesn't have `<caption>` like so :

```
foreach (HtmlNode rows in htmltable.SelectNodes("tr[not(.//caption)]"))
{
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    .....
    .....
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```